# Ruby - Turning a CSV into a Hash that contains a ratio as the value

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a **CSV** file that contains 4 columns, though only two relevant ones.

Column A contains a large group of sometimes repeating strings e.g. (Apple, Banana, Apple, Apple, Cherry) and column B contains one of two strings ("W" or "L").

I'm trying to turn this data into a Hash with a key for each unique string in column A, with the value being the % of the total rows per that key that were "W".

e.g. if the CSV were the following:

```
 ColA   ColB
"Apple" "W"
"Apple" "W"
"Apple" "L"
"Banana" "W"
```

the hash would be:

```
{"Apple" => 66%, "Banana" => 100%}.
```

I've managed to create a hash that groups my rows together by doing the following:

```
fullset = CSV.read('file.csv')
groupedhash = fullset.group_by {|x| x[1]}
```

and I've managed to find the individual counts for the second column like so:

```
groupedhash.map{|k,v| [k, v.select.count {|x| x[2] == "W"}]}
groupedhash.map{|k,v| [k, v.select.count {|x| x[2] == "L"}]}
```

But I've been unable to figure out how to put it all together and get the actual "W" ratio.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another counting hash variant:

```
arr = [["Apple", "W"], ["Apple", "W"], ["Apple", "L"], ["Banana", "W"]]

h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = { 'W' => 0, 'L' => 0 } }

arr.each { |a, b| h[a][b] += 1 }

h #=> {"Apple"=>{"W"=>2, "L"=>1}, "Banana"=>{"W"=>1, "L"=>0}}
```

We can now get the (exact) ratio by:

```
h.transform_values { |v| v['W'].quo(v['L'] + v['W']) }
#=> {"Apple"=>(2/3), "Banana"=>(1/1)}
```

or (rounded) percentages via:

```
h.transform_values { |v| v['W'].fdiv(v['L'] + v['W']) * 100 }
#=> {"Apple"=>66.66666666666666, "Banana"=>100.0}
```

or maybe a string representation:

```
h.transform_values { |v| sprintf('%d%%', v['W'].quo(v['L'] + v['W']) * 100) }
#=> {"Apple"=>"66%", "Banana"=>"100%"}
```

Comment: Thank you - I think the transform_values method was what I was trying to find but couldn't.

Comment: Excellent answer! Sartake, note that [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) made its debut quite recently, in Ruby v2.4.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you have read the data into an array,

```
arr = [["Apple", "W"], ["Apple", "W"], ["Apple", "L"], ["Banana", "W"]]
```

and then grouped its elements by fruit,

```
h = arr.group_by(&:first)
  # => {"Apple"=>[["Apple", "W"], ["Apple", "W"], ["Apple", "L"]],
  #     "Banana"=>[["Banana", "W"]]}
```

You can obtain the desired result by simply recomputing the values of this hash.

```
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = 100.0 * h[k].count { |_,t| t =="W" } / h[k].size }
  #=> ["Apple", "Banana"]
h #=> {"Apple"=>66.66666666666667, "Banana"=>100.0}
```

An alternative is to use a *counting hash*. See the doc for [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), particularly in regard to the use of a default value, which here is the array `[0, 0]`.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new([0,0])) { |(fruit, type), h|
      h[fruit] = [h[fruit].first + (type == "W" ? 1 : 0), h[fruit].last + 1] }.
    tap { |g| g.keys.each { |k| g[k] = (100.0 * g[k].first/g[k].last).round(2) } }
  #=> {"Apple"=>66.67, "Banana"=>100.0}
```

The intermediate result is as follows.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new([0,0])) { |(fruit, type), h|
      h[fruit] = [h[fruit].first + (type == "W" ? 1 : 0), h[fruit].last + 1] }
  #=> {"Apple"=>[2, 3], "Banana"=>[1, 1]}
```

If `Hash.new([0,0]` is still perplexing, we could write the above line as follows.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |(fruit, type), h|
  h[fruit] = [0, 0] unless h.key?(fruit)
  h[fruit] = [h[fruit].first + (type == "W" ? 1 : 0), h[fruit].last + 1]
end
```

Notice that I've used [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) to avoid the need to create the variable `h` when using `group_by`, and then returning the value of that variable by adding the line `h` at the end. Furthermore, I've rounded the results to two decimals. Both of these techniques could of course be used with the method that employs `group_by`.

Comment: Thank you Cary, explaining this in detail is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
fullset = CSV.read('file.csv')
groupedhash = fullset.group_by { |x| x[0] }
result = groupedhash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, values), hash|
  w_count = values.select { |x| x[1] == "W" }.length
  hash[key] = (w_count / values.length.to_f).round(2)
end
```

Comment: To determine `w_count` you don't need to select the tuples that contain `"W"`, and then determine the size of the resulting array. Simply use `values.count { |x| x[1] == "W" }`.